# Can one be *highly* ambivalent?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, modifiers, writing-style

I've always felt that it's something of a contradiction to be *very* or *highly* ambivalent.  It's grammatically correct, as far as I know, but is it stylistically acceptable, or is my sense of linguistic style correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambridge [defines](http://dictionaries.cambridge.org/define.asp?key=ambivalent%2a1+0&dict=A) the adverb form thusly:

> having two opposing feelings at the same time, or being uncertain about how you feel

...and *highly* ambivalent would mean the same, but to a greater extent. While correct, the phrase is fairly empty without something to compare it to. One could be ambivalent about [x] and *highly* ambivalent about [y].